# link figure to jpg file in such a way

Tags: cross-referencing

how can I link figure in tex in this way, i.e.

"Fig.\,6(b)" in tex, then I click Fig.\,6(b), I will see the 6.jpg automatically

namely What should I do in

```
\begin{figure}[h]
....
\end{figure}
```

Best,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place a unique `\label{foo}` after the caption of your image, you can reference it with `\ref{foo}`.

A combination of a couple of packages can make it easier to get your desired format:

- `hyperref` to make the cross references clickable
- `subcaption` to split a figure in multiple subimages numbered with a, b etc
- `cleveref` to automatically insert `fig.` before the figure number in the cross reference

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\cref{imageb}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{text}
\label{imagea}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{text}
\label{imageb}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if I need fig.1a-1f ? Thanks !

Comment: @ABCDEMMM You can use `\cref{labela,labelb,labelc,labeld,labele,labelf}`, cleveref  will automatically compress these into a-f if you reference all labels.

Comment: I got errors: tex capacity exceeded, sorry[input stack size=5000]

Comment: @ABCDEMMM can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: can i use subfig? if yes, then how??

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Without seeing a MWE all I can do is gues: subfig might or might not work (has some problems with links which seem to be important for you), but I personally prefer the `subcaption` package, which has more features, is easier to use and  interacts perfectly with the useful `caption` package.

Comment: thanks, \hfill function is also supported?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM `\hfill` is unrelated to any `subfig` or `subcaption` packages

Comment: @okay I will not use subfig any more, thanks for your support!

Comment: \includegraphics[width=2.2cm] can be used in subcaption???

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Why would it not be possible to use this? If you encounter some problem, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Without knowing anything about your document I will only be able to guess.